# What's wrong with my /summon command? [1.12]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use this command:

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:388,Count:1,tag:{}}}
```

But the command block returns with "Unable to summon object".
What am I doing wrong? I'm using Minecraft version 1.12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numeric item IDs are no longer supported, use the item's string name instead:

```
/summon item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:"emerald",Count:1}}
```

Comment: I recognise why it had to change, but it still makes me sad we can't spawn things in with numbers. I had so many IDs memorised.